# Rails javascript does not work on heroku cedar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, production

I'm trying run my app on heroku in producer environment, but my javascript does not working there.
I my development environment it was working fine. So when i pushed it to heroku it sets down.

My gem file is that:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'bourbon'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'asset_sync'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'fog'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.8.0'
    gem 'webrat', '~> 0.7.3'
    gem 'simplecov'
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'heroku'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form.git'
gem 'devise'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'validates_cnpj'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'delocalize'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'simple-navigation'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'koala'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

So my assets is compiled correctly, no errors, and all them are send to amazon s3.

if i put the line on the head of HTML, some javascript begin to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

in my app there is a gmaps, when I debug my app I found that the javascript just works where was the map, so I put this line above on the head and the javascript begin to work.

Someone can help me with it? I don't know why this problem in my app.

thanks